# Call instance Method inside Sub document mongoose hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are some fields in my Subdocument schema that I want to validate before saving to the database . However, if they are not valid, instead of failing, I just want to set them to undefined . I Defined the two functions on

```
ServerSchema.method
```

But when I try to access them in the hook, I get the error

```
this.conditionallyRemoveFields Is not a function
```

However, this only happens when saving the top level document, and is not when saving the server alone . When I save the server a loan, there are no errors . Here is the hook

```
ServerSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
   this.conditionallyRemoveField(this.shouldRemoveField, ["Apple","orange"]);
   next();
});
```

Any idea what might be going on ? Also, is this even the right approach for this problem ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was to define the methods before defining the parent schema. After doing that, everything worked perfectly.